# Is there a way to get text only voltage and current labels on Simscape circuits?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

I am new to Simscape. I would like to find a minimalist way to display voltage and current at various points in a circuit. Ideally just floating text labels with no 'wires' or connections visible. For example "Vbe 0.4v" or "Ic 20mA"

Currently I am using 3 standard blocks to achieve this and the circuit looks cluttered.

Is there a way to do what I want with some coding?

Comment: If you have no connections, what do you expect the measurements to relate to? Simulink isn't an app interface, it is a coding interface - the clarity of where signals are connected is integral to how it works. Please show a screenshot in an [edit] to your question to clarify what you have now vs what you would like.

Comment: There will be connections, but they won't be visible. I can't attach an image because this is my first question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you have several options, some involve more work. Here are two ideas:

A) If your circuit is 3-phase, you can use the [Busbar](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/ref/busbar.html) block and enable [Frequency and Time](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ug/frequency-and-time-simulation.html) solver in the [Solver Configuration](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/solverconfiguration.html) block, to display the initial voltages (and also power flows). This uses the [Load-Flow Analysis](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/ug/perform-a-load-flow-analysis-using-simscape-electrical.html) feature starting R2019b. Check out [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/examples/2-bus-loadflow.html) simple example.

B) Connect [Voltage Sensor](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/voltagesensor.html) blocks to the nodes you want to sense voltage on, and connect the voltage PS output to a Simulink [Display](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/display.html) block, which will display the numerical value in real-time.